# autopilot does not work

Tags: juju, maas

I tried to install OpenStack Autopilot according to the instructions from [here](http://Https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot), everything went well until the point *6. Launch OpenStack Autopilot*.

```
Snap install conjure-up --classic OK
Conjure-up --bootstrap-to <hostname> not work

$ Conjure-up --bootstrap-to ROOM822-OA15-Bay3
Usage: conjure-up [-h] [-d] [-s] [--version] spell
Conjure-up: error: unrecognized arguments: --bootstrap-to
```

Comment: instruction [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You need to verify the path where conjure-up is installed then run `conjure-up --bootstrap-to <hostname>` from there.

```
$ which conjure-up
/snap/bin/conjure-up
$ /snap/bin/conjure-up --bootstrap-to <hostname>
```